# exclude files from being sent over github actions

Tags: azure, github, mern

Im trying to find out if there is a way to exclude certain files from being sent over github actions, for example, i have a server and a client in the same repository. right now, both the server (node.js) and the client (its a react.js application) are being hosted together on azure app services. once the `/` is hit, it serves up the `index.html` file from the build folder.

however I am finding that hosting these two things together is taking its toll on the overall application, for example, it sometimes takes up to 10 seconds for the server to respond and return the index file to the client. I remember in my training some of my more senior devs didnt like to host the server and client together, and im starting to see why..

so I likely will need to split these up to improve performance, but before i go through a daunting task of splitting the repositories up. is there a way to specify in github actions in a workflow to ignore certain files/folders etc..

the only modification i've made to this is that i added an action to zip the application for faster upload to azure to improve workload performance.

here is my workflow:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          
      - name: unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
        
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'Omitted'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{SECRET}}
          package: .
```

Comment: You can refer to [Exclude files/dirs either by name or regexp](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/44)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shell script that excludes the files you don't want.
In `.github`, create a new folder `scripts`. Inside the `scripts` folder, create a new file named `exclude.sh`.

In the `exclude.sh`, add the following:

```
zip -r [file_name.zip] [files/folder to zip] -x [file path/name to exclude]
```

In your workflow:

```
- name: unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip file_name.zip
```